# How to install Ubuntu Linux from DVD drive for Acer Aspire 5333

Tags: 16.04, drive

even if I make the cd-rom priority 1 in the boot sequence, it does not start up the Ubuntu 16.4 boot disk.

The boot disk seems in good shape.

I would appreciate any advice,
Leon

Comment: are you booting UEFI? secure boot needs to be off

Comment: The Acer Laptop is on Windows 7, so I think I am still using BIOS. I tried to switch off Secure Boot, but no such option as far as I could figure out. Much appreciated your comments.

Comment: most likely you are BIOS boot, the CD should boot either way

Comment: Yes I know, that is why I am so perplexed by this.

Comment: In 2017 use USB sticks. Ubuntu doesn't even fir in a CD, only DVD. If you want to use optical media make sure it has been properly burned: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#0

Comment: Also, if you have Secure Boot options itś UEFI, however, your Windows 7 was most likely installed in Legacy. You should then boot and install Ubuntu in the same mode.